# wget failed: Connection timed out

Tags: linux, wget

I have the following command to copy the website,

as it tried to hit sun.com it got connection timed out.

I would like the wget to exclude the sun.com so that wget would proceed to the next thing.

Exisitng Issue

```
$ wget --recursive --page-requisites --adjust-extension --span-hosts --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows http://pt.jikos.cz/garfield/
.
.
2021-08-09 03:28:28 (19.1 MB/s) - ‘packages.debian.org/robots.txt’ saved [24/24]

2021-08-09 03:28:30 (19.1 MB/s) - ‘packages.debian.org/robots.txt’ saved [24/24]
.


Location: https : //packages. debian. org /robots.txt [following]
--2021-08-09 03:28:33--  https : //packages. debian. org /robots.txt
Connecting to packages.debian.org (packages.debian.org)|128.0.10.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 24 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘packages.debian.org/robots.txt’

packages.debian.org 100%[===================>]      24  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2021-08-09 03:28:34 (19.1 MB/s) - ‘packages.debian.org/robots.txt’ saved [24/24]

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2021-08-09 03:28:34--  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Resolving wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)... 137.254.16.75
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-08-09 03:28:56--  (try: 2)  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-08-09 03:29:19--  (try: 3)  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-08-09 03:29:43--  (try: 4)  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-08-09 03:30:08--  (try: 5)  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-08-09 03:30:34--  (try: 6)  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-08-09 03:31:01--  (try: 7)  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

Expected $wget to save the whole website without timeouts, if there are timeouts then wget would skip the timeout connections.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the fine manual about the "risks" of using the `--span-hosts`
(`-H`) option and how to limit those by adding restrictions:
https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Spanning-Hosts

> The `--span-hosts` or `-H`  option turns on host spanning, thus allowing Wget’s recursive run to visit any host referenced by a link. ***Unless sufficient recursion-limiting criteria are applied, these foreign hosts will typically link to yet more hosts, and so on*** until Wget ends up sucking up much more data than you have intended.

...

> **Limit spanning to certain domains `-D`**
> The `-D` option allows you to specify the domains that will be followed, thus limiting the recursion only to the hosts that belong to these domains.

...

> **Keep download off certain domains `--exclude-domains`**
> If there are domains you want to exclude specifically, you can do it with `--exclude-domains`, which accepts the same type of arguments of `-D`, but will exclude all the listed domains.